# 2 Random Walkers on 2d square lattice, Torus

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walks, brownian-motion

I am looking for the probability that two random walkers initially at different sites, meet at step t if they are moving on a 2-dimensional torus(Square Lattice)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Surely you need to say the initial probability distribution of where they start, if you want to work out the probability of when something else (that depends on where they start) happens.

Comment: Like @znt said, you need to   give more details if you expect a precise answer. Is is a *discrete* time random walk, or is it a *continuous* time random walk. In either case  you need to give more details about the transition probabilities.

Comment: I am supposing that they start at (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) on my square lattice. They do a discrete time random walk. and they are doing a simple random walk so they hop to their neighboring sites with equal probabilities.

Comment: Just to be sure: you mean "meet for the first time at time $t$", or "be at the same location at time $t$"?

Comment: Thank You for your question. Be at the same location at time t.

Comment: Note that you may need some additional assumptions depending on the sizes of the toric square lattice. For instance, on the 2d discrete $2n$x$2m$ torus, which is a bipartite graph, the two random walkers can meet only if they start on vertices of the same parity (or if they have a non-zero probability of not jumping).

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be ot fix one random walker and look a the law of the difference, i.e., instead of looking at the distance between $X_1$ and $X_2$, you look at the distance between $X_1-X_2$ and the origin.
But in here, since the two walkers have the same law and are (I guess) independent, you can write: 
$$\begin{align} 
P_{(a,b)}(X_1(t)=X_2(t))&=\sum_ {x\in T}P_a(X_1(t)=x)\times P_b(X_2(t)=x) \\ 
&=\sum_ {x\in T}P_a(X_1(t)=x)\times P_x(X_1(t)=b) \\
&=P_a(X_1(2t)=b) \\
\end{align}$$
where $P_{(a,b)}$ means that $X_1(0)=a$ and $X_2(0)=b$, and $T$ is the set of vertices of the torus.

Comment: in your first equality, you used the assumption that the random walks are reversible, correct?

Comment: Correct. This is the case here since the walkers do a simple random walk on the square torus, see the comment of klara.d.